# Java.sql.ResultSet bug for rs.next()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

The SQL code works and next() function outputs true or false but is not accepted by the if (condition).

```
boolean status = res.next();
if (res.next()) {
     System.out.println("first");
 } 

if (status) {
      System.out.println("second");
}
```

The code above has the same semantics but the one using the method next() doesn’t work.

Comment: Welcome. Could you share some code ?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a reproducible example. Also, did you have a question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Are you invoking `next()` twice? Once to assign it to the boolean and once in your `if` condition?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to do it to check where the error is coming from, SQLException doesn’t show any exception at all and the other code seems to work except for this one.

Comment: Thanks guys. Nevermind. I just figured out that I can’t really call the next() function twice.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or book. Please post a complete question/post from that, otherwise it is difficult  to answer your question clearly.

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem. Please accept one of these answer by clicking the tick sign next to it. It will turn green once you click it. It means you have accepted this answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

If there is only one record in the resultset, `status` will be true but the next attempt of `res.next()` will return `false`. Thus, the following code will output only `second`.

```
boolean status = res.next();
if (res.next()) {
     System.out.println("first");
 } 

if (status) {
      System.out.println("second");
}
```

If there are two records in the resultset, you will get both, `first` and `second` as the output.

To summarize,

1. Output when there is only one record in the resultset

```
second
```

2. Output when there are two records in the resultset

```
first
second
```

Comment: What is he trying to achieve. I do not understand.

Comment: @Aman OP is wondering why "first" is not printed. Seems clear enough to me.

Comment: Thanks Arvind. I just figured it out awhile ago but yeah you have the right answer. I’m fairly new to stack overflow but the community here is great. Much respect!

Comment: And Federico really gave me the hint from his previous comment @Federico

Answer (score 0):

What you did making the result set to move to the second row because you call `next()` twice

, You can check this one:

```
if (res.next()) {
     System.out.println(“first”);
 } else {
      System.out.println(“second”);
 }
```